# Synonyms: [powermock] and [powermockito]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

I think that [powermock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powermock) and [powermockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powermockito) are actually referring to the same thing.

I would suggest synonymize them, or even a merge. At this case, I think would be better keeping [powermock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powermock), 770 questions per 22 of [powermockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powermockito).

I do not have enough reputation to do that, so I've considered convenient to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not referring to the same thing.

PowerMock is meant for users who actually use EasyMock.  PowerMockito is meant for users who use Mockito.  Having worked with all three, **there is a difference.**

While both talk about the same general thing (mocking static methods and generally doing other mocks that the base mocking framework - either EasyMock or Mockito - cannot do), they are *not the same thing*.

Comment: Thanks for clarify @Makoto, apparently I've been confused about it for a long time...Judging by some questions about these two tags, I think there are more people confused like me. Thanks again